# why this pointer value changed after adding virtual keyword in C++

Tags: c++, this

Consider below line of code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
int i;
public:
void printb()
{
cout << "This pointer of base   "<<this<<endl;
}
};

class derived: public base
{
int i;
public:
void printd()
{
cout << "This pointer of derived "<<this<<endl;
}
};

main()
{

derived d1;
d1.printd();
d1.printb();
}
```

After compiling with g++(4.8.4) in 64bit ubuntu machine result is

```
This pointer of derived 0x7ffe74697ac0
This pointer of base    0x7ffe74697ac0
```

As per my understanding both base and derived ***this*** pointer will be same since we are calling with single object.
I added virtual keyword to printd() function of derived class as below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
int i;
public:
void printb()
{
cout << "This pointer of base   "<<this<<endl;
}
};

class derived: public base
{
int i;
public:
virtual void printd()
{
cout << "This pointer of derived "<<this<<endl;
}
};

main()
{

derived d1;
d1.printd();
d1.printb();
}
```

output of above code is as below

```
This pointer of derived 0x7ffee969b1d0
This pointer of base    0x7ffee969b1d8
```

Here ***this*** pointer value is different in derived and base even if calling with single object.Every time i run the program there is difference of 1byte between derived ***this*** pointer and base ***this*** pointer.
Can anybody tell why this difference in ***this*** pointer and how virtual keyword affect ***this*** pointer.

Comment: It's not 1 byte, it's a whole 8 of them. A pointer's worth of bytes on your platform.

Comment: Because you obliged the compiler to lay down a virtual function table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding the `virtual` keyword, you made `derived` polymorphic. A common implementation of runtime polymorphism is to add a pointer to the start of the object. This *vptr* points to a table of functions that are dynamically dispatched (commonly known as a *vtable*).

As such, the `base` sub-object, which is not polymorphic, is offset inside the `derived` super-object by the hidden pointer.

You see the pointer adjusted automatically, because the compiler injects code to perform this adjustment upon calling a member function. This ensures that `printb` will access all the (potential) members of `base` in the correct location.